# MySQL left outer join with where clause - return unmatched rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables: **pq** and **pe**. I am trying to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` left table (**pq**) on right table (**pe**).

- **pq** has primary key column *id*
- **pe** has two-column primary key, so it may have many pqid's or none
- **pe**.uid column has to be used to extract only relevant data (`WHERE pe.uid = "12345"`)
- **pe**.data should be joined to every **pq**.id row

Here is how tables look:

```
pq:
id | data
1  | "abc"
2  | "efg"

pe:
pqid | uid   | data
2    | 54321 | "uvw"
2    | 12345 | "xyz"
```

I can use the following query to match first 2 rows of **pq**.id to **pe**.pqid

```
SELECT pq.id, pq.data, pe.data FROM pq
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pe ON pq.id = pe.pqid
    ORDER BY pq.id LIMIT 2
```

I get:

```
pq.id | pq.data |  pe.data
1     | "abc"   |  
2     | "efg"   |  "uvw"
```

But if I use the WHERE statement like this:

```
SELECT pq.id, pq.data, pe.data FROM pq
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pe ON pq.id = pe.pqid
    WHERE pe.uid='12345'
    ORDER BY pq.id LIMIT 2
```

I only get one row with matching **pe**.pqid AND **pe**.uid:

```
pq.id | pq.data |  pe.data
2     | "efg"   |  "xyz"
```

So with the WHERE clause I get the right **pe**.data, but I don't get **pq** rows that have no **pq**.id matching **pe**.pqid

I need to get this:

```
pq.id | pq.data |  pe.data
1     | "abc"   |  
2     | "efg"   |  "xyz"
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes.  The `where` clause is turning the left outer join into an inner join.

Why?  The value of `pe.pqid` is `NULL` (as is `pe.uid`) when there is no match.  So the comparison in the `where` clause fails (almost all comparisons to `NULL` return `NULL` which is considered false).

The solution is to move the comparison to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT pq.id, pq.data, pe.data
FROM pq LEFT OUTER JOIN
     pe
     ON pq.id = pe.pqid and
        pe.uid='12345'
ORDER BY pq.id LIMIT 2
```