# num_rows() not returning correct number of row when result is not empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, mysql-num-rows

I am working on one Join query in CodeIgniter. Query run perfectly fine. 
The problem is `$query->num_rows()`.This is how I write my join query.

```
$this->db->select('related colums');
$this->db->from('table1 as t1');
$this->db->join('table2 as t2', 't1.id = t2.id', 'left outer');
$this->db->join('table3 as t3', 't1.id_second = t3.id', 'left outer');                                                          
$this->db->where('t1.column', $some_varibale);
$this->db->order_by("t1.column", "desc");
$query = $this->db->get();

$query_result = $query->result_array();
$number_of_row = $query->num_rows(); // This line of code is not working properly. 

print_r($number_of_row); 

// To check result is empty or not.

if(!empty($query_result)){
    echo 'not empty';
} else {
    echo "empty";
}
```

#### The problem:

When I print the `$number_of_row` it gives me 13 but when I print `$query_result` it will show only one row which is correct result.(I have double checked it)
so the problem is I was expecting that `$query->num_rows()` will return me 1 if I get only one row in the result.

I have the cross check it when I get an empty result then it will show 0 as expected. but as described before when I get one row in result it will show 13 number.

I am aware of `count` and it will work but the question is why this `$query->num_rows()` not working correctly?

I didn't get that what am I doing wrong?

Comment: why don't use `count($query_result)` ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion count will help me but why this num_row not working is my question. @Aidin

Comment: move where clause into on clause, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910729/mysql-left-outer-join-with-where-clause-return-unmatched-rows

Comment: I'm not sure what's the issue with your code but it is indeed correct. Tried replicating it and `num_rows()` worked as intended. Maybe if you can share more of the actual code, otherwise we can't replicate the problem.

Comment: @hyubs ok i will edit the question and add some of  actual code. Thanks

Comment: Not sure, why this is not working, because when looking at the source code, it should return the same number as the results returned in `result_array()`: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1-stable/system/database/DB_result.php#L130 Just a guess: Is `$query_result` an array of arrays or just a one-dimension array. Use `print_r($query_result)` or debug Codeigniter itself.

Comment: I have tried that both option sir i have used the Codeigniter log and also try to use `print_r` for result it was same as described in question, for info: this query is the only query in the function of model. @Residuum is join query is doing any thing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$number_of_row = $this->db->affected_rows();
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: affected rows behave same as num_rows. I have try that before. thanks